# SQLAlchemy how to create a relationship or mapping of a table's "type" row to the table model or mixin

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I need to set the entity_type_id as a column value when I persist a row to a generic table of various entity_types.  I should be able to load the entity_type_id for every specific instance at instantiation time because it is accessible via a simple select statement.  I'd like to have that id automatically retrieved/set at the class (or instance) level without executing a query and/or manually setting to every time I persist a row of an "entity_type".

I tried an entity_type_id @property on the mixin that returns the id of the entity_type using the object_session but for reasons I don't fully understand the orm still inserts null as the entity_type_id value when I commit/flush the session.  (my guess is having the "property" itself isn't the same thing as setting the attribute value on the instance and/or causing an issue because the column name from the base class has the same name)

Here's a slimmed down version of the relevant models in my schema:

```
class EntityType(Base):
__tablename__ = 'entity_type'

id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, server_default=FetchedValue())
table_name = Column(String, nullable=False)
ui_label = Column(Text, unique=True, nullable=False)
entry_key = Column(Text, unique=True, nullable=False)
```

Base class model:

```
class TrackedEntity(Base):

@declared_attr
def __tablename__(cls):
    return convert(cls.__name__)

__table_args__ = (
    UniqueConstraint('entity_type_id', 'label'),
)

id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, server_default=FetchedValue())
entity_type_id = Column('entity_type_id', ForeignKey('entity_type.id'))
label = Column('label', String, nullable=False)

entity_type = relationship('EntityType')

polymorphic_discriminator = column_property(select([EntityType.table_name]).where(EntityType.id == entity_type_id).as_scalar())

@declared_attr
def entity_type_label(cls):
    return association_proxy('entity_type', 'label')

@declared_attr
def __mapper_args__(cls):
    if cls.__name__ == 'TrackedEntity':
        return {
            "polymorphic_on": cls.polymorphic_discriminator,
            "polymorphic_identity": cls.__tablename__
        }
    else:
        return {"polymorphic_identity": cls.__tablename__}
```

Children class mixin:

```
class TrackedEntityMixin(object):
        # noinspection PyMethodParameters

    @declared_attr
    def id(cls) -> Column:
        return Column(ForeignKey('tracked_entity.id'), primary_key=True)
    #gets me the id but isn't very helpful like this, still needs to be manually set like child.entity_type_id = child._entity_type_id
    @property
    def _entity_type_id(self):
        return object_session(self). \
            scalar(
            select([EntityType.id]).
                where(EntityType.table_name == self.__tablename__)
        )
```

A child class model:

```
class DesignedMolecule(TrackedEntityMixin, TrackedEntity):


      extra = Column('extra', String)
      parents = relationship('TrackedEntity', secondary='mix_dm_parent_entity')
```